# Only text after clicking the example for directions API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Instead of displaying a map after clicking one of the Example Directions Requests
on the following API directions tutorial https://goo.gl/rnFLAo only text is being displayed at the opening page.
I do have a functioning API key for a browser.
What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start of with a tutorial with a detailed source code that can walk you through the step by step implementation of getting the API key and till displaying the Google Map in the Fragment Activity.

You can take a look at this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/) which uses images and modular code to help you explain the over all process and would walk you through the steps.

Hope it does help.